# web2py server returns error but query is commited

Tags: javascript, database, web2py

I have a db insert statement in my controller code. After user inserts text, clicks save it is saved into database, but the javascript part of the code returns error. This only occurs if page is accessed from another computer. If I run it from localhost of the server no error is returned

Any ideas?

Thank you

here is my code

the controller in default.py

```
def add_item():

acedata =  request.body.read()
data = gluon.contrib.simplejson.loads(acedata)
ace_script =  str(data["podatki"])
PgSQL = db_conn() ## connect to db
cur = PgSQL.cursor()

sql = """
        INSERT INTO datoteke(
                file_name, file_text)
        VALUES ('%s', '%s');""" % ('neki', ace_script)

cur.execute(sql)        
PgSQL.commit()
PgSQL.close()
print "DONE!!!"
return dict()
```

and my javascript part

```
function okClicked () {
    var scr_name = $('#txt_shranikot').val(),
        dat = {'podatki' : saveContent(), 'name' : scr_name}, 
        data = JSON.stringify(dat),
        savedScripts = {{=XML(skripte)}};
    console.log($.inArray(scr_name, savedScripts));
    if ($.inArray(scr_name, savedScripts) != -1)  {
        console.log("NE!!!!")
        $(".modal-body").prepend('<div class="alert alert-danger">To ime skripte že obstaja</div>');

    } else {
        //$("#saveNewScript").data-dismiss="modal"
        $("#saveNewScript").attr('data-dismiss','modal');
        doPost("{{=URL('default', 'SaveNew')}}", data);

    }
};

 function doPost(callback, data) {
  $.post(callback, data, function(data){})
  .done(function() { alert("Done!"); })
  .fail(function() { alert("Failed!");})
 }
```

Comment: In your controller, why do you use cursors, and SQL statements? The DAL in web2py has so many nice features...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably do not have an add_item.html view file. On localhost, by default web2py will use generic.html when a specific view file does not exist (assuming you start with the scaffolding app and keep the line in db.py that enables generic views on localhost). Otherwise, you will get an error. Note, the insert is committed because the error occurs after the add_item() function returns.

If you don't need the add_item action to execute a view and generate any HTML, then instead of returning a dict, just return a string (e.g., "Success").